# Python3 Flask API - Sending and receiving image as bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, image

I am using the following code to send images as byte array to a python3 flask api.  When I am sending a image from the server which is serving the api, I get the response, though with some errors, however, when I send an image from an external machine to the server, I am getting getting an attribute error indicating that the image is not delivered.  The following is the code and the error messages:

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import io
import requests
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/lastoneweek', methods=['POST'])
def get():
    print(request.files['image_data'])
    img = request.files['image_data']
    image = cv2.imread(img.filename)
    rows, cols, channels = image.shape
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2, rows/2), 90, 1)
    dst = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (cols, rows))
    cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', dst)
    ##do all image processing and return json response
    return 'image: success'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=5000,debug=True,threaded=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**client.py**

```
import requests

with open("test.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    # f = imageFile.read()
    # b = bytearray(f)    
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/lastoneweek'
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, files=[('image_data',('test.jpg', imageFile, 'image/jpg'))])
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.json())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    # res = requests.put(url, files={'image': imageFile}, headers=headers)
    # res = requests.get(url, data={'image': imageFile}, headers=headers)
    ##print received json response
    print(response.text)
```

***When I send the image from the same machine which renders the api***, I get the following message:

```
200
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The intention is to save a file with the name `'output.jpg'`.  This is getting accomplished.

***When I send the image from an external machine*** to the server, I get the error 500 with following message:

```
rows, cols, channels = image.shape
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

indicating that the image had not reached the server.  My images are around 2.5 MB each.  I am afraid if the api gets triggered even before the complete bytearray is delivered.

How do I send images as bytearray and make opencv read the same.  I am equally open to other options as well as long as it is python.

Comment: first check what you have in `print( image )`. `cv2.imread` works in unexpected way - when it can't read file then it return `None` instead of rasing error.

Comment: `img.filename` can gives you only filename but not full path to file on disk - so cv2 may not read it because it can't have full path. You should rather use `img.read()` to get directly data. I don't know if `cv2.imread()` can use directly data but there should be encode() or somehing similar, Eventually you can write  `img.read()` to `io.BytesIO` to create file-like object in memory and `cv.imread()` should works with file-like object instead of filename.